# Spring cloud dataflow not connecting to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run my spring-dataflow-server-local with MySQL DB. But it says,

" java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) "

I am running on my Windows Machine.

I used the same user name and password to connect to the same mysql from MySQL Workbench successfully.

I am running the dataflow server with the following command.

```sh
java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/task_db --spring.datasource.username=username --spring.datasource.password=password --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

Please help me on how to fix this? anyone faced similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested that the data flow server starts successfully using

- Windows 10
- MySQL 8.0.15
- Java 1.8.0_66

With the same command line that you show.  I used jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/task_db and created the task_db schema before running the data flow server in the workbench.

When installing MySQL 8.0.15 there was an option for 'enhanced login security' or 'classic' security.  I picked 'classic'.

Would need to know more of how your MySQL is set up.

To isolate things, try going through the getting started guide - there is a 'completed' folder you can just run - https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ and see if you have any connection issues.

Comment: Thanks @MarkPollack I will go through and update the status here.

Comment: I tried with the "complete" example. The example project connects and creates the "user" and "hibernate_sequence" tables. But, when i use the same user name and password to connect spring cloud dataflow server, it is giving me the same error.  " java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example --spring.datasource.username=springuser --spring.datasource.password=ThePassword --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver "